# Show that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z^{n}X_n = 0 $ for $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|z|<1$. Let ${(X_n)}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complex valued random variables with $\mathbb{E}{X_t}=0$ and finite $\mathbb{Var}X_t = \mathbb{Var}{X_0}$.
I want to show that

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z^{n}X_n = 0.
$$

I can show that $|z|^{n}X_n \overset{L^2}{\longrightarrow}0$ by writing
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}|z^nX_n|^2 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|z|^n \mathbb{E}|X_n|^2 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|z|^n \mathbb{Var}X_0 = 0.
$$
How can one proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see $L^2$-convergence doesn't help here.

---

There is the following useful result which states that "fast" convergence in probability implies convergence almost surely:

> Let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|Y_n-Y| \geq \epsilon) < \infty$$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Then $Y_n \to Y$ almost surely.

Use Markov's inequality (or the Tschebysheff inequality) to show that $Y_n := z^n X_n$ satisfies

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon)<\infty$$

for all $\epsilon>0$. By the above theorem, this implies $z^n X_n \to 0$ almost surely.